# How can I change the Class of SELECT fields that Joomla generates'

Tags: css, form, form-fields-types, jhtml

I've disable `chosen.js` so that all my `<select>` tags are plain HTML, but am so far unable to change the default class of `inputbox` to one of my choosing, 
(specificially from the Search Tools filters of my component page).

I've looked at a number of answers and tutorials about overriding forms, but I'm either not understanding the examples, or looking at the wrong kind of overrides.

Ultimately, I want to change the class of any `<select>` that is generated in `libraries\cms\html\select.php`.  I've tried adding the path/file to my template, but can't get that to do it.  I see that it's generating the field with `$options` as below, but I can't figure where THAT is being determined and supplied.

```
$options Array (
    [format.depth] => 0
    [format.eol] => 

    [format.indent] =>  
    [id] => filter_event_group_id
    [list.attr] => class="inputbox" onchange="this.form.submit()"
    [list.translate] => 
    [option.key] => value
    [option.text] => text
    [list.select] => 
)
```

My attempts at specifying it in the XML at [List form field type](https://docs.joomla.org/List_form_field_type) are failing as well - the page just comes up blank, though that was a shot in the dark because my field is actually a [SQL Form Field Type](https://docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type) which apparently does NOT support the Class parameter like the Select does.

```
<field name="created_by" class="MyChosenClassname" type="sql"...`
```

So, the question is either how do I add this override to my template properly, or how do I specify the Class name to be used in the generated `<select>` tags?

Comment: Just curious. The class name is nothing magical in itself, why not just use that class name in your css and do whatever you need through that?

Comment: @Arlen The class IS in my CSS, but the Joomla function(s) have no mechanism to include that class name for field type SQL when it generates the select list.  Having that class name in the CSS isn't the problem, it's having the class name included in the select list for jquery to do what it needs to do.

Comment: Umm, apparently I was unclear: Why not stop insisting on your own class name and use the one Joomla uses? Just seems simpler to me to create news styles for an existing class name than try and force a new class name into the system. I'm all for the path of least resistance until I see a good reason not to. Which is why I asked.

Comment: @arlen I'd normally wholeheartedly agree, and if had been as simple as styling a dropdown list, I certainly would have, but it was a year ago, and i don't remember the particulars .  I do recall depending on the parameters to work as they should, but the class name being specified were not being considered for SQL field types, which where I'd been spinning my wheels.

Comment: Hmm. OK, yeah, I see that. Seems the SQL field type is discouraged for anything really complex (read: useful) in favor of creating a custom field instead. I'd probably begin to create the custom field by trying to extend the JFormFieldSQL class (libraries/joomla/form/fields/sql.php) to add code to get and set the class. FWIW, but probably too late to help.

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to add a custom class using jQuery.

just put this javascript code snippet in the head section of your template, the majority of template/frameworks providers supports custom javascript code to be added easily.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('select').addClass('custom_class'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add the `class` attribute to the XML field, like so:

```
<field name="foo" class="MYCLASS" type="list" label="My List">
    <option value="0">Option 1</option>
    <option value="1">Option 2</option>
</field>
```

Comment: For a <select> field, tat will will work, but not for a SQL field type.